# in linux using boost xml_parser how to read and compare windows-1251 literals?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

In Linux I have something like this:

```
boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml(argv[1], pt);
// huge parsing
            for (auto const& itemNode : rootNode2.second) {
                const pt::ptree& dealAttributes = itemNode.second.get_child("<xmlattr>", empty_ptree());
                for (auto const& dealAttr : dealAttributes)
                {
                    const std::string& attrName = dealAttr.first;
                    const std::string& attrVal = dealAttr.second.data();
```

- Original xml is windows-1251.
- attrVal is russian literal
- I need it to compare with constant in my program.

How should I define this constant? It seems in Linux default Russian enconding is not Windows-1251 so my comparision failes.

Here's a sample xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="cp1251"?>
<root>
    <item accounting_currency_code="RUB" board_name="ФБ Т+2"
        broker_commission="71.85" broker_ref="3/00/2"
        conclusion_date="2013-09-11T00:00:00" conclusion_time="2013-09-11T11:04:35"
        deal_no="480" execution_date="2013-09-12T00:00:00" price="144.700000"
        price_currency_code="RUB" request_no="1976"
        security_grn_code="1-02-008-A" security_name="ГАЗПРОМ ао"
        sell_qnty="5000.00000000" volume_currency="718500.00"
        volume_rur="718500.00"/>
</root>
```

Comment: The command **locale -a** will show which locales are available on your system, i tested it in Ubuntu but i dont have Windows-1251

Comment: there is a solution here to add **Windows-1251** in Ubuntu: http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=220034.0

Comment: Do you have a sample XML? So we know what you're talking about and can test?

Comment: @sehe I'm afraid of giving example xml because it contains confidentional information. In general I need to tune `boost::property_tree::xml_parser` for proper encoding and declare literals in my code using the same encoding.

Comment: Come on. You can get a sample anonymized much easier than we can. Just make something up? As long as it demonstrates the issue...

Comment: put example here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49126809/report.xml I need to read "security_name" value and compare it with literal. in linux.

Comment: @javapowered Juuuust too late. You can try my answer with your sample :)

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI and that's the other time I saw you contribute complete nonsense (that forum.ubuntu.ru link is bogus to this topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the steps I made to "success" with a "random sample":

1. #### Create sample input:

   Call it e.g. `input.xml` and make sure it's saved in cp2151:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
   <root>
     <deal id="1" silly="е">
           hello
       </deal>
   </root>
   ```

   That's a U+0435 (Name: CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE) right there.
2. #### Configure your system to support cp1251 locales

   For me I had to

   - edit /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local adding `ru_RU.CP1251 CP1251`, then
   - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`
3. #### Imbue!

   Use `read_xml` and `write_xml` that imbue a specific locale.

   Use Boost Locale to generate the locale instance that knows the character set conversion *facets*:

   ```cpp
   boost::locale::generator gen;
   auto loc = gen.generate("ru_RU.CP1251");
   ```
4. #### Profit

> **Note** I had to take special precautions to verify the contents of the 'debug.xml' file. My vim misdetected the encoding, showing it as latin1 (`"å"` instead). I used
>
> ```
> :ed ++enc=cp1251 debug.xml
> ```
>
> To force the correct codepage.

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00e25f18b41562be)</kbd>**

```cpp
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/locale/generator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

static ptree const& empty_ptree() {
    static ptree _instance;
    return _instance;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    assert(argc>1);
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    auto loc = gen.generate("ru_RU.CP1251");

    ptree pt;

    read_xml(argv[1], pt, 0, loc);

    ptree::value_type& rootNode2 = *pt.begin();

    // huge parsing
    for (auto const& itemNode : rootNode2.second) {
        const ptree& dealAttributes = itemNode.second.get_child("<xmlattr>", empty_ptree());
        for (auto const& dealAttr : dealAttributes)
        {
            const std::string& attrName = dealAttr.first;
            const std::string& attrVal  = dealAttr.second.data();

            std::cout << "Attribute '" << attrName << "' hath value "; // '" << attrVal << "'\n";

            int pos = 1;
            for (uint8_t ch : attrVal) // prevent sign-extension
            {
                if (pos++ == 8) {
                    std::cout << '\n';
                    pos = 1;
                }
                std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::showbase << static_cast<int>(ch) << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    auto settings = boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4, "windows-1251");
    //boost::property_tree::xml_parser::write_xml_element(ofs, "root", pt, 0, settings);
    write_xml("debug.xml", pt, loc, settings);
}
```

It runs on Coliru, including the locale support (kudos, Coliru!), and hex dumps the `debug.xml` for verification:

```
Attribute 'id' hath value 0x31 
Attribute 'silly' hath value 0xe5 
0000000: 3c3f 786d 6c20 7665 7273 696f 6e3d 2231  <?xml version="1
0000010: 2e30 2220 656e 636f 6469 6e67 3d22 7769  .0" encoding="wi
0000020: 6e64 6f77 732d 3132 3531 223f 3e0a 3c72  ndows-1251"?>.<r
0000030: 6f6f 743e 0a20 2020 200d 2623 3130 3b20  oot>.    .&#10; 
0000040: 200d 2623 3130 3b0a 2020 2020 3c64 6561   .&#10;.    <dea
0000050: 6c20 6964 3d22 3122 2073 696c 6c79 3d22  l id="1" silly="
0000060: e522 3e0d 2623 3130 3b20 2020 2020 2020  .">.&#10;       
0000070: 2068 656c 6c6f 0d26 2331 303b 2020 2020   hello.&#10;    
0000080: 3c2f 6465 616c 3e0a 3c2f 726f 6f74 3e0a  </deal>.</root>.
```

As you can see, `0x22 0xe5 0x22` is the correct hex representation of `"е"` in cp1251

Comment: The recorded livestreams of me answering this question are here: **[part #1](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-propertytree-support-russian-cp1251-1/)** and **[part #1](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-propertytree-support-russian-cp1251-2/)**. ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469)). As you can see, I tried your sample XML too and it worked fine :)

Comment: if you declared string literal somewhere which you compare with security_name attribute value?

Comment: Ah. Should not be problem IFFFF (!!) your source uses cp1251 encoding. Safest way would be to use e.g. `"\xe5"` in my example. If your data is UNICODE, you're in for canonicalization etc.